# Native HTML grouping href links for reuse a best maintenance

Tags: html

I have recently started to do markdown documentation and it has a very useful feature that allows you to group all the links in a single place and reuse them by calling your reference. This greatly facilitates the maintenance of documents.

For example in markdown the code of reusable links would look like this:

```
[Abbreviations]: http://pythonhosted.org/Markdown/extensions/abbreviations.html
[Attribute Lists]: http://pythonhosted.org/Markdown/extensions/attr_list.html
[Definition Lists]: http://pythonhosted.org/Markdown/extensions/definition_lists.html
[Fenced Code Blocks]: http://pythonhosted.org/Markdown/extensions/fenced_code_blocks.html
[Footnotes]: http://pythonhosted.org/Markdown/extensions/footnotes.html
[Tables]: http://pythonhosted.org/Markdown/extensions/tables.html
[Smart Strong]: http://pythonhosted.org/Markdown/extensions/smart_strong.html
```

These links can be used anywhere in the document simply by calling your reference name, for example:

```
* `abbr` -- [Abbreviations][]
* `attr_list` -- [Attribute Lists][]
* `def_list` -- [Definition Lists][]
* `fenced_code` -- [Fenced Code Blocks][]
* `footnotes` -- [Footnotes][]
* `tables` -- [Tables][]
* `smart_strong` -- [Smart Strong][]
```

I've searched a lot and I have not found any similar feature using only native HTML.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: This is one of the (many) reasons why template languages exist :)

Comment: Hi! José Luis could you give me detail of your solution based on templates ... I do not know

Answer (score 0):

Technically this *is* possible via javascript at runtime - though for the sake of hypertext document integrity, I would not advise it in a production environment:

```js
// SET UP REFERENCES OBJECT

var references = {

  abbr : {
      text : 'Abbreviations',
      hyperlink : 'http://pythonhosted.org/Markdown/extensions/abbreviations.html'
    },

  footnotes : {
      text : 'Footnotes',
      hyperlink : 'http://pythonhosted.org/Markdown/extensions/footnotes.html'
    },

  tables : {
      text : 'Tables',
      hyperlink : 'http://pythonhosted.org/Markdown/extensions/tables.html'
    }

}


// LOOP THROUGH REFERENCES OBJECT

Object.keys(references).forEach(function(reference) {

    var text = references[reference].text;
    var hyperlink = references[reference].hyperlink;
    var referenceSet = [...document.getElementsByClassName(reference)];

    referenceSet.forEach(function(referenceAnchor) {
        referenceAnchor.setAttribute('href', hyperlink);
        referenceAnchor.textContent = text;
    });
});
```

```html
<ul>
<li><a class="abbr"></a></li>
<li><a class="footnotes"></a></li>
<li><a class="tables"></a></li>
<li><a class="abbr"></a></li>
<li><a class="footnotes"></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Rounin Is a good solution ... but with JavaScript ... I'm looking for a solution that only implies HTML / CSS (for security restrictions)

Comment: I'm fairly certain you will not be able to insert an `href` attribute into an anchor element without using javascript.

Comment: ... I was afraid of that !!! ... but hope is never lost :-) ... I was hoping someone would know something new (HTML5, CSS) or some old trick